# Какой Linux посоветуете для работы c Андроид Студио исходя из моих критериев оценки?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, поиск-программ

Критерии оценки:

1. Чтобы **Андроид Студио** встала туда без проблем.
2. Чтобы отладка на подключаемом (внешнем) устройстве (телефоне / планшете) нормально функционировала.

Поделитесь советом (опытом), пожалуйста!

Идея вопроса в том, чтобы, хотя бы, **исключить** из рассмотрения те Линуксы, которые для моих целей не очень подойдут! ) Сэкономить кучу времени на переборе и экспериментах! ) Для меня этот вопрос ОЧЕНЬ ПОЛЕЗНЫЙ и ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНЫЙ! И для моих студентов тоже! ) 
Опыт сообщества реально может помочь мне (нам) сузить поиск и сэкономит уйму времени, возможно, и нервов )))

Comment: сейчас в активной разработке – версия 4 программы linux. берите её и ошибётесь.

Comment: Спасибо! Alexander, Вы имели в виду "не ошибетесь"? )

Comment: Любой, все линуксы одинаковые

Comment: Странно, что вопрос признан "порождающим прения, основанные не на знаниях", и в итоге: не полезным! Попросить совет в таком важном, основополагающем вопросе и услышать мнения опытных разработчиков по поводу операционных систем оказалось за пределами дозволенного! Кстати, все ответы очень полезны и основаны на практическом опыте и практическом знании! Потому что опыт - сын ошибок трудных и гений парадоксов - друг! Большое спасибо тем, кто поделился своим ценным опытом!

Comment: Хорошо, вы посчитали, что вопрос надо закрыть, но а минус то зачем  ставить??? Минус означает, что он, вопрос, не имеет пользы... Для меня этот вопрос архиважен, и любой ответ, особенно с отрицательным опытом - архиполезен!!! Почему вы посчитали, что вопрос не полезный когда он АРХИПОЛЕЗНЫЙ!!!

Comment: Почему ответы отвечающих заминусовали? Да за каждым ответом - ГОДЫ ПРАКТИКИ! БЕСЦЕННОЙ ПРАКТИКИ! Я считаю, что вы не правы с оценкой этого вопроса и ответов на них. Вопрос этот важный и очень полезный для многих разработчиков, кто задумывается о Линукс!

Comment: @YuriK, вопросы вида "какой дистр выбрать" совершенно бесполезны, потому что каждый будет советовать свой любимый вариант, не взирая на то, какую задачу вы хотите решить.

Comment: А отвечающим минусы понаставили за компанию. Кроме того, если на закрытый вопрос не будет положительно оценённых ответов, он будет удалён автоматически через некоторое время.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вопрос, который я задал очень полезен для меня (и многих). И те ответы, которые мне дали за несколько часов до запрещения - уже оказали большую помощь в ориентировании. Пострадали люди, которым поставили отрицательные оценки ЗА ТО, ЧТО ОТ ДУШИ ПОДЕЛИЛИСЬ ЦЕННЫМ ОПЫТОМ! Вопрос признан "порождающим прения, основанные не на знаниях". Услышать мнения опытных разработчиков по поводу операционных систем оказалось за пределами дозволенного! – Yuri K 3 часа назад

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 года работаю в Android Studio на Linux Ubuntu через ноутбук. Никаких нареканий нет. С подключением устройств тоже проблем никогда не было, даже с самыми китайскими устройствами - главное разблокировать меню разработчика.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с предыдущим оратором - Ubuntu лучший выбор. Правда, есть одна маленькая засада - нужно устанавливать Sun JDK вместо Open JDK, на OpenJDK были проблемы, сейчас не знаю как, но таки рекомендуется православная Sun JDK.

Установка Sun JDK требует некоторых танцев с бубном.

Пробовал еще Arch Linux, типа спец.дистрибутив для Android девелоперов, но как то *не взлетел*

Comment: Огромное Спасибо! За Ваш опыт! И Совет!

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать Mint. Работаю около года на нем, вроде ничего не слетает. IDE вставала без костылей и т.п.